# get list of countries from wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, country-codes

is it possible to get list of country names and country codes somehow from phone? E.g. the list of countries is displayed in Settings.

Or can I easily get country name from country code like gb,de,fr,cs,...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of absence of some functions in silverlight version of CultureInfo  and RegionInfo I decided to use resource file with international code and international country name.

The list of countries is provided here: https://gist.github.com/901679

I really don't know why silverlight version doesn't support same functions like .NET version of Culture/RegionInfo.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a simple list you can store it locally and retrieve it using a number of options (resx, sql db, etc).

However if you want to detect the country based on the region/country code please consider the following option:

```
using System.Globalization

string countryCode = "en-US"; 
try {
    RegionInfo reg = new RegionInfo(countryCode);
        string name = reg.Name;
        string displayname = reg.DisplayName;
        string ISORegion = reg.TwoLetterISORegionName;
        string currency = reg.CurrencySymbol;
} 
catch (ArgumentException argEx) {
    // The country code was not valid 
}
```

More Info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: this would be great, but it is not working. When I try your example on WP7 it returns "Value does not fall within the expected range." exception.
So I tried to get info about CurrentRegion: RegionInfo.CurrentRegion and it has all fields empty except DisplayName which is in my case Czech Republic.

Comment: Made a slight modification, also noted that "US" is not valid you need to be more specific with the culture. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can get the cultures in code, but here is a list of *Accepted Cultures*

- USA, English, en-US
- UK, English, en-GB
- Germany, German, de-DE
- France, French, dr-DR
- Spain, Spanish, es-ES
- Italy, Italian, it-IT
- Canada, English, en-CA
- Canada, French, fr-CA
- Australia, English, en-Au
- Mexico, Spanish, es-MX
- Ireland, English, en-IE
- New Zealand, English, en-NZ
- Belgium, French, fr-BE
- Austria, German, de-AT
- Switzerland, French, fr-CH
- Switzerland, German, de-Ch
- Singapore, English, en-SG
- Hong Kong, English, en-HK

Comment: thanks, but I need it to access by twoletter code, because that is what I get from web service.

Comment: An 'official' culture code is 4 letter. Scrap the last 2 if you want

Answer (score 0):

In my thought, there is no API to you get all the countries supported from the Settings.

But you can refer the following link to get the all the [Culture and language supported for Windows Phone.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202918%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)